# Can't display all characters in the loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, char

I've wrote a simple cipher (not supposed to hard) that ciphers a given string by changing the characters to char and adding the index to chek to scramble the values. The problem is, when I decipher the code it cuts the last character. Now I'm sure this is a simple rookie mistake but I'm struggling to find the culprit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Cipher {

    public void cipher(String strArg) {
        String placeholder = strArg;

        System.out.println("Unciphered text: "+placeholder);

        char[] charArg = placeholder.toCharArray();

        char[] cipheredArg;     
        int lengthArg = charArg.length-1;       
        cipheredArg = new char[lengthArg];

        System.out.print("Ciphered text: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthArg; i++) {
            char current = charArg[i];
            cipheredArg[i] = (char) (current + i);
            System.out.print(cipheredArg[i]);
        }

        System.out.print("\nDeciphered text: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthArg; i++) {
            char current = cipheredArg[i];
            charArg[i] = (char) (current - i);
            System.out.print(charArg[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cipher show = new Cipher();
        show.cipher("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Unciphered text: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Ciphered text: Tig#uzojs)l}{?|/v??3~????9????>???B????G???
Deciphered text: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

As you can see the dot is missing in the deciphered text. Any ideas?

Comment: `int lengthArg = charArg.length-1;` why `-1`?

Comment: That easy, huh? Thanks a bunch, I knew it would be something obvious. For some reason I thought .length counts from 1 not 0 and was sure this would make my loops go out of bounds but I guess I was wrong. Kudos, my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are double-compensating for zero-based indexing in Java

This reduces the length to iterate by one

```
int lengthArg = charArg.length-1;
```

as does this due to the < operator

```
for (int i = 0; i < lengthArg; i++) {
```

The canonical fix would be to use the full length of the array and the < operator

```
int lengthArg = charArg.length;       
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < lengthArg; i++) {
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < charArg.length; i++)
```

Becouse char array should be in length of 0..n-1, but looks it's n elements. Like, You have word "Hello" and array starts with element 0 which is "H" to 4 which is "o". And looks it's 5 elements. I hope it helps You out.

Comment: crashes with IOOBE because of `cipheredArg = new char[lengthArg]`

Comment: Yes, You right, I though it was obvious and focus on other things. My mistake :)